# Creating 16 or 32 bit image from byte array

Tags: java, image, image-processing, swt, rgb

Given the width, height, depth and byte array of an image, I need to create an SWT Image object.  Currently, I have no trouble when given the data for 8 bit images.

```
int imageWidth;
int imageHeight;
int depth;
byte[] imageBytes;
//calculate the values

imageData = new ImageData( imageWidth, imageHeight, depth, new PaletteData(255,255,255), 1, imageBytes);
new Image( display, imageData );
```

The problem I have is that for 16 bit images the color is a bit off.  What should be black pixels are actually gray.

For 32 bit images, only a few black pixels show up and the rest of the image is white.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Edit:  The imageBytes array is read from a proprietary graphics file that I have been unable to get the specification for(and so I am not entirely sure of the format).

I was able to make some progress on the 32-bit image.  It looks like the 32 bit image was in one of the RGBAX formats.  I converted it into a 24-bit image and it now has the same problem as the 16-bit image(what is gray should be black).

The size of the imageBytes array is (width * height * (depth/8) ) where depth is in bits.

I tried changing the byte ordering of each pixel however it didn't solve the problem.  In areas that should be solid black, it would either be black, a mixture of white and black or be all white.

Comment: It sounds like the key to solving your problem is understanding the proprietary format that you're dealing with.  Unless you completely understand the format, it is possible that you're not populating `imageBytes` correctly when reading 16 or 32 bit images.  This means that the problem probably occurs before the code you posted is executed.  If you share the images, the full code you are using to read it and screenshots of the results you are getting, you may be able to get help with understanding the image format.  Without that information, there isn't a lot more I or anyone else can do.

Answer (score 0):

From the symptoms you describe, it's possible that you're experiencing endian issues.  It looks like Java's `byte` datatype is [8-bits only](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/), so when you're constructing your 16-bit images, a total of two Java `bytes` makes up a single pixel in the constructed image.  Obviously, For 32-bit images, the number of Java `bytes` per pixel will be 4.

For example, in a big-endian 32-bit world, `[0 0 0 255]` would be a pretty dark gray (essentially black).  On the other hand, in a little-endian world it would be pretty close to white.

Some questions:

- How are you populating your `imageBytes` array?
- What are its dimensions?  One would assume it would be `width*height*depth/8` if `depth` is in bits.

Some things you could try:

- Read the SWT documentation to find out the endianness that the `ImageData` constructor expects
- Shuffle the `bytes` within a single pixel in your `imageBytes` array.  For example, in the 32-bit case, `[0 0 0 255]` becomes `[255 0 0 0 ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Given that (a) you are working with an unknown graphics format and (b) you are having gray issues, I suspect that the high bit is not for color but for some other feature (perhaps transparency / alpha). This could easily make an expected all black image 50% gray.

Try a simple bit op on each image byte (or 16 bits or ...) and set the high bit to zero.

For a single byte, ie:
`finalByte = originalByte & 0x7f;`

It's also possible that this bit is a marker for run length encoding (RLE), or other varint encoding, but if you're getting the correct image sizes / dimensions, this is probably not the case.